# Realm Swiftで主キーが存在しない場合のみ追加し、存在している場合は一切何もしない方法はありますか。

Tags: swift, realm

普通に追加すると、既に主キーが存在している場合はエラーでクラッシュします。
以下のように、追加する前に既に存在するかチェックするようにしてみましたが、何か違うような気がします。

```
// id(主キー)が5のDogが存在しなければ追加し、存在すれば何もしない
let dogs = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("id == 5")
if dogs.count == 0 {
    realm.add(newDog)
}
```

初歩的な質問ですがよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

考え方はそれで合っています。Realmには同じプライマリキーを持つオブジェクトがある場合は新しいデータで「更新」するというAPIは用意されています（`add(_, update:)`）が、古いデータの方を残すというAPIはありません。

（もし目的がそっちなら

```
realm.add(newDog, update: true)
```

と書くと古いオブジェクトを自動的に更新してくれます。）

なので、すでにオブジェクトが存在するかどうかをチェックして、存在する場合は何もしない、という処理を書きます。

ただし、プライマリキーを設定しているのに`filter()`で検索する必要はありません。
プライマリキーがあるオブジェクトでキーが分かっているなら、`object(ofType:forPrimaryKey:)`でプライマリキーを使ってオブジェクトを取得できます。

```
if realm.object(ofType: Dog.self, forPrimaryKey: 5) == nil {
   realm.add(newDog)
}
```